# how do I write the test cases for the method with in the method?

Tags: testing, junit, mockito, code-coverage, testcasesource

How can I write the j unit test cases for the method within the method? please, help me out to resolve this issue. Here "CreatePreparedStatement" is the method within the create device history method .

```
@Override
@Transactional
public DeviceHistory createDeviceHistory(DeviceHistory dh) {
    Timestamp currentTime = CommonRoutines.getUTCTimestamp();

    dh.setCreatedAt(currentTime);
    dh.setUpdatedAt(currentTime);
    dh.setActive(1);

    GeneratedKeyHolder holder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
    int rowCount = provJDBCTemplateRepository.executeUpdate(new PreparedStatementCreator() {
        @Override
        public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
            PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(DeviceQueries.INSERT_INTO_DMS_DEVICE_HISTORIES,
                    new String[] { "LOG_ID" });

            statement.setString(1, dh.getTransactionId());
            statement.setObject(2, dh.getDeviceGroupId());
            statement.setString(3, dh.getEventType());
            statement.setString(4, dh.getMessageCode());
            statement.setString(5, dh.getMessageTextEnUS());
            statement.setObject(6, dh.getSmartAccountId());
            statement.setObject(7, dh.getVirtualAccountId());
            statement.setString(8, dh.getTenantId());
            statement.setObject(9, dh.getDeviceDetailId());
            statement.setString(10, dh.getSeverity());
            statement.setObject(11, dh.getHasAPICEMLog());
            statement.setObject(12, dh.getParentLogId());
            statement.setObject(13, dh.getActive());
            statement.setString(14, dh.getCreatedBy());
            statement.setTimestamp(15, dh.getCreatedAt());
            statement.setString(16, dh.getUpdatedBy());
            statement.setTimestamp(17, dh.getUpdatedAt());

            return statement;
        }
    }, holder);

    LOGGER.debug("Rows Updated createDeviceAlerts- ", rowCount);
    dh.setLogId(Long.valueOf(holder.getKey().toString()));
    return dh;
}
```